# Force cli utility to write to stdout when it provides no config options and only writes to a file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, stdout, command-line-interface

I have to work with an ancient cli tool that I cannot modify. It writes a bunch of pipe delimited records to a file. I do not need any of this data persisted to disk, I just need it written to stdout so it can be picked up by an automated process through an ssh session. Is there a way to avoid the unnecessary overhead the tool goes through to persist the records to disk and trick it to just write to stdout?

Comment: If the tool requires a regular file, then the answer is no.  Try using /dev/tty as the file name, and you might get lucky.

Comment: How do you specify the output file name?  Is it an argument on the command line?  Is it in a config file?  Or what?

Comment: It uses a default filename. There actually is an option that allows you to specify the filename, but it prompts you for it interactively. So you have to type `cmd -f` then hit enter and it says `Enter preferred filename:`. I know there are ways to provide programatic input to interactive prompts, just can't remember exactly how? More importantly, I can't have this interactive prompt get sent to stdout and picked up by the ssh session. Everything the ssh session picks up from stdout has to be a valid pipe delimited record. I know this is crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the file name in advance, you could create a FIFO with that name before you start the program. However, it is quite possible that it will refuse to run in this scenario.

```
mkfifo output.dat
# Set up a reader of some sort
# This just writes to stdout
tail -f output.dat &
pid=$!
oldprog >/dev/null
rm output.dat
kill "$pid"
wait $"pid"
```

This simplistically assumes that you do not need to interact with `oldprog`, or at the very least that its standard output can be discarded, so it doesn't disturb the output from the `tail` process.  Maybe try `oldprog >&2` if you need to see what you are doing.

Comment: I'm guessing `tail -f output.dat >/dev/null &` is where I would use something that writes to stdout for the ssh session to grab? Sorry for the noob question but if it's running as a background job with `&` how would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Updated with an answer which simply runs `tail` to stdout and discards any output from `oldprog`.  Perhaps you need something a little more elaborate, but this is the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

In bash:

```
$ cli_tool -f <<< >(automated_process)
```

Explanation:

- `>(automated_process)` is a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution). `automated_process` reads from stdin the results produced by `cli_tool` that writes to a special named file.
- `<<<` is a [here string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString) that feeds the fifo name or named file descriptor (`/dev/fd/...`) created by the process substitution to `cli_tool` stdin (`cli_tool -f` reads a filename of where to write results from stdin)

On my system the command may be equivalent to:

```
# run in the background, read from /dev/fd/63
automated_process < /dev/fd/63 & 
# pass the line "/dev/fd/63" literally to `cli_tool`
cli_tool -f <<< "/dev/fd/63"
```

The effect is that `cli_tool` prints the prompt `"Enter preferred filename:"` and gets `/dev/fd/63` string as a filename i.e., `cli_tool` write to `/dev/fd/63` file, `automated_process` reads from the `/dev/fd/63` file. No content touches the disk.

On systems without named file descriptors `>()` could be implemented using fifo:

```
mkfifo filename 
automated_process < filename &
cli_tool -f <<< "filename"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you help me out and provide a little info on what's going on here?

Comment: Ah, I see! I think that gets me very close, but does it handle the fact that I can't actually pass the fifo name or named file descriptor to `-f`? `-f` is just a flag, it does not accept a parameter. It causes the utility to then prompt for the filename interactively: `Enter preferred filename:`.

Comment: yes. It does handle it. It is why `<<<` is there. Try `cat` instead of `automated_process` to see the result in stdout (there is a delay due to buffering).

Comment: Awesome! One last issue, it looks like the tool is trying to append it's normal extension to the fd so it is unable to open it: `Failed to open /proc/self/fd/13.txt`. Any ideas?

Comment: @foobar0100: If cli_tool doesn't respect the filename that it is given then the process substitution won't work. Try to create a named pipe with the cli_tool's default filename and see whether it accepts non-seekable files. btw, you should put the info about cli_tool that is scatttered in comments into your question.